# Call WCF REST Service from Win Form Application

Tags: c#, json, winforms, wcf-rest

I am creating a test tool to test my WCF REST services. This return data as json. For testing pupose i have created a tool which have on textbox to give the json string as input. So the data is deserialized to dataset or datatable and show as grid. This is for readbility and for data testing.

My existing button method like below

```
    pnlOutput.Controls.Clear();
    JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(txtInput.Text));
    string data = "";
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        data += reader.Value;
    }

    if (data.Contains("Table"))
    {
        DataSet ds;
        ds = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(data);


        int topPosition = 0;
        foreach (DataTable dataTable in ds.Tables)
        {
            DataGrid grid = new DataGrid();
            grid.DataSource = dataTable;
            pnlOutput.Controls.Add(grid);
            grid.Top = topPosition;
            grid.Width = pnlOutput.Right - 10;
            grid.Height = (pnlOutput.Height / ds.Tables.Count) - 10;
            topPosition = grid.Height + 5;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        DataTable dt;
        dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(data);
        DataGrid grid = new DataGrid();
        grid.DataSource = dt;
        pnlOutput.Controls.Add(grid);
        grid.Width = pnlOutput.Right - 10;
        grid.Height = pnlOutput.Height - 10;

    }
```

The tool take input as json string. Now i m thinking to add one more textbox so that i can give the service url directly to that testbox. In a button click in need to get the json data from the url and do the functionalities as old one.

Can anyone help me to identify the possibilities of this. I don't need to add service reference as this is a general tool to test any WCF service.

Comment: What do you mean by "identify the possibilities of this"?

Comment: sorry for my english. Actually i mean i need to get the data directly from the service without adding service reference. From jquery we can directly call the service method using url Likewise i am trying in Win Form application

Comment: You can use a `HttpWebRequest` for that. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492678/call-wcf-service-by-httpwebrequest

Comment: So can i use HttpWebRequest from Windows Form Application. So i dont need to add service reference?

Comment: Thanks friend it worked out and i finished it